# Security Warning from Google Play! Vulnerable Classes

Tags: java, android

Google Play has canceled my publication and wrote this warning:

> Your application is using an unsafe version of HostnameVerifier.
>   Vulnerable classes: com.independentsoft.exchange.Service $ 1

[Link to the library](http://www.independentsoft.de/jwebservices/index.html).

Perhaps he points to these pieces where:

```
} catch (ServiceException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  return e.getMessage();
}
```

What can I do? How do I solve my problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "how do I solve my problem?" -- what do you mean? You never thought of *not* using that unsafe version?

Comment: Ask the developers of that library if they have a newer version that does not use an unsafe `HostnameVerifier`. If they do, upgrade to that newer version of the library. If they do not, get rid of the library.

Comment: @TimCastelijns Google Play never gave me such a warning. And this is a very old project. Please write me a sample code how to change this?

Comment: @CommonsWare I used the latest version of this library.

Comment: *Please write me a sample code how to change this?* - remove the library from the project

Comment: @TimCastelijns This is the first thing I thought about, but my project uses "exchange" to schedule a meetigns. Do you think there are no other solutions?

Comment: Then I just have to change a lot in the code, I would not want to.

Comment: it doesn't look like you have a choice

Comment: @TimCastelijns I think you're right! Ok, Thank you!